# Assign Future<var> to var

Tags: flutter, dart, async-await

I have some code written in dart where I use the provider package to update the location of a pin on a map. What I would like it to do is have the initial location be equal to the user's current position and then if they drag the pin it will be updated to wherever the pin is dropped.

My problem is that the initial location variable needs to `Future<LatLng>`, however, when I update the location it ends up being just `LatLng` and I cannot assign it to the `_location` variable.

```
class LocationProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  Future<LatLng> _location = LocationService().getLocation();

  // Error here, wants it to be Future<LatLng>
  LatLng get location => _location; 

  void calculateNewLocation(oldLocation, zoom, offset) {
    var newPoint = const Epsg3857().latLngToPoint(oldLocation, zoom) +
        CustomPoint(offset.dx, offset.dy);
    LatLng? newLocation = const Epsg3857().pointToLatLng(newPoint, zoom);

    // Error here again for the same reason
    _location = newLocation ?? _location;

    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

How do I make it so that I can assign both of these values to `_location`?

Comment: probably get location returnig future? what is your location service library?

Comment: just add "await"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply have a method for that in provider file

```dart
class LocationProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  LatLng? _location;

  LatLng? get location => _location; 

  Future<void> initializeLocation() async {
    _location = await LocationService().getLocation();
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void calculateNewLocation(oldLocation, zoom, offset) {
    var newPoint = const Epsg3857().latLngToPoint(oldLocation, zoom) +
        CustomPoint(offset.dx, offset.dy);
    LatLng? newLocation = const Epsg3857().pointToLatLng(newPoint, zoom);

    _location = newLocation ?? _location;

    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Then, you'll have to call `initializeLocation` when you want it to be initialized, like:

```dart
Future<void>? _myFuture;

final _provider = Provider.of<LocationProvider>(listen: false);
_myFuture = _provider.initializeLocation();
```

and then in `FutureBuilder`, provide `_myFuture` in `future`

PS: `?` can be excluded if you're not using dart in `null safe` mode

Comment: By the way after doing this it happens to be that `_location` is not initialized fast enough so I get a couple of seconds an error whilst it is getting initialized. I was thinking of fixing it with a `FutureBuilder` but that variable is no longer regarded as `Future`. Do you know of a possible fix for this?

Comment: in that case, change the return type of `initializeLocation` to `Future<void>`
and store `_provider.initializeLocation();` in a variable like
```dart
Future<void>? _myFuture;

_myFuture = _provider.initializeLocation
```

and in FutureBuilder, provide `_myFuture` in `future`

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code,

```
LocationService().getLocation() returns a future, so you have to either await/async or use then().
```

try these

```
Future<LatLng> _location = LocationService().getLocation();
LatLng get location = await _location;  // put this in a separate method with async keyword
```

or

```
LocationService().getLocation().then((value) { location = value } );
```

Comment: you cannot use the word `await` without `async`, so you won't be able to `await` there like that

talking about this line here
`LatLng get location = await _location;`

Comment: plus, even if you could, that'll still be a `Future<LatLng>`

Comment: @imadipanshus - thanks for pointing out  that.